# Conditional sum for time period R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a large set of data that includes a start time, stop time and value.  The start and stop times vary from row to row and are in 5 minute increments.  I am trying to create a new data frame that has a 5 minute interval and the sum of all rows where the interval is within the start and stop of a row.

I have a script that works, but it uses a for loop that calculates the sum for each row of my interval data frame.

Any advice on how to do this more quickly and efficiently?  It currently can take very long to run.

Sample data set 
"data"

```
start           stop           Volume
7/1/2013 0:00   7/1/2013 1:00   10
7/1/2013 0:15   7/1/2013 1:00   5
7/1/2013 0:30   7/1/2013 0:40   3
7/1/2013 0:50   7/1/2013 0:55   1
```

Sample Output
data frame named "sum_mw"

```
IntervalStart   IntervalEnd     Sum_Volume
7/1/2013 0:00   7/1/2013 0:05   10.00 
7/1/2013 0:05   7/1/2013 0:10   10.00 
7/1/2013 0:10   7/1/2013 0:15   10.00 
7/1/2013 0:15   7/1/2013 0:20   15.00 
7/1/2013 0:20   7/1/2013 0:25   15.00 
7/1/2013 0:25   7/1/2013 0:30   15.00 
7/1/2013 0:30   7/1/2013 0:35   18.00 
7/1/2013 0:35   7/1/2013 0:40   18.00 
7/1/2013 0:40   7/1/2013 0:45   15.00 
7/1/2013 0:45   7/1/2013 0:50   15.00 
7/1/2013 0:50   7/1/2013 0:55   16.00 
7/1/2013 0:55   7/1/2013 1:00   15.00
```

Here is the sample code I am using.

```
   library(lubridate)

    data$start<-mdy_hm(data$start,tz="UTC")
    data$stop<-mdy_hm(data$stop,tz="UTC")

    sum_mw$IntervalStart<-mdy_hm(sum_mw$IntervalStart,tz="UTC")
    sum_mw$IntervalEnd<-mdy_hm(sum_mw$IntervalEnd,tz="UTC")

    sum_mw$Sum_Volume<-0

    for (i in 1:nrow(sum_mw))
    {
    sum_mw$Sum_Volume[i] <- sum(data[data$start<=sum_mw$IntervalStart[i] & data$stop>=sum_mw$IntervalEnd[i],][,3],na.rm=T)
    }
```

Comment: You probably can use rolling join in data.table, but my usage of it is a bit rusty :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an option in `tidyverse`.  After converting the columns to DateTime class, use `map2` to loop over the corresponding 'start', stop' values, get a `seq`uence of times `by` `5 min`ute interval, `unnest` the `list` column, grouped by 'Interval', get the `sum` of 'Volume'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_at(1:2, mdy_hm) %>% 
   transmute(Interval = map2(start, stop, seq, by = '5 min'), Volume) %>% 
   unnest(Interval) %>% 
   group_by(Interval) %>% 
   summarise(Sum_Volume = sum(Volume))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(start = c("7/1/2013 0:00", "7/1/2013 0:15", "7/1/2013 0:30", 
"7/1/2013 0:50"), stop = c("7/1/2013 1:00", "7/1/2013 1:00", 
"7/1/2013 0:40", "7/1/2013 0:55"), Volume = c(10L, 5L, 3L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```